# Фильтрация выборки из базы данных

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, ado.net

Друзья, подскажите, как сделать фильтрацию выборки из базы данных.
Допустим есть таблица, в ней 5 полей.
Пользователь может сделать выборку по 1, 3 и 5 полями. Может по 2 и 5 полями. Заранее не известно.
Как формировать запрос с помощью LINQ динамически? Если заведомо я не знаю, что выберет пользователь.

Т.е. я имею в виду как формировать запрос подобного вида "на лету"

```
var list = dataBase.MyTable.Where(x => x.Field2 == "test").Where(x => x.Field5 =="test-test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем модель для фильтрации, (пользователь заполнит поля по которым нужна выборка):

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public string FileldOne { get; set; }
    public int? FileldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Испотльзуем вот так:

```
public class MyEntityService
{
    public IQueryable<Entity> GetEntityByFilter(FilterModel filter)
    {
        var result = Context.Entity.AsQueryable();
        if (filter!= null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.FileldOne))
                result = result.Where(x => x.FileldOne == filter.FileldOne));
            if (filter.FileldTwo.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.FileldTwo == filter.FileldTwo);
        }
        return result;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Модель фильтрации должна содержать те же поля, что и моя сущность?

Comment: Только поля по которым нужна выборка, на Ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Еще вопрос, почему Вы по первому полю делаете одну проверку, а по-второму - другую?

Comment: ошибся, исправил тип на string

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Составляйте IQueryable из нужных вам фрагментов.

Вместо:

```
var instances = await this.Db.Instance
    .Where(x => x.OwnerID == userID && x.Archieved == archieved)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Пишите:

```
var instancesQuery = this.Db.Instance
.Include(x => x.Product.Collection.Brand)
.Include(x => x.PrimaryImage)
.Where(x => x.OwnerID == userID);

if (something1)
{
    instancesQuery = instancesQuery.Where(x => x.Archieved == archieved);
}

if (something2)
{
    instancesQuery = instancesQuery.Where(x => x.PrimaryImageID == null);
}

var instances = await instancesQuery
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToArrayAsync();
```