# Получить имя свойства в Func C#

Tags: c#

Как получить имя свойства из `Func<T, string>`?

Есть метод `void Example(Func<MyClass, string> func) { ... }`

Обращаюсь к методу `MyMethod(x=> x.MyProperty)`

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Что то не могу найти нигде ответа или примера(везде примеры с `Expression<func<t,string>>`..

Comment: Из функции — никак, используйте Expression.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Тут нужно понимать матчать, как это всё устроено.

Делегат - это просто метод (указатель на метод), который что-то принимает и что-то возвращает (в частном случае - void), вы можете как написать:

```
Example(x => x.MyProperty);
```

Или в классе оформить явно делегат:

```
delegate string Operation(MyClass source);
```

И использовать запись:

```
Func<MyClass, string> operation = x => x.MyProperty;
Example(operation);
```

В делегате больше ничего и нет внутри, не хранится ничего кроме указателя на метод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Совсем другое дело — дерево выражений. В нём как раз хранится информация о

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, string>> expr = x => x.MyProperty;
Example2(expr);
Example2(x => x.MyProperty);

public void Example2(Expression<Func<MyClass, string>> expr)
{
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И можно разобрать выражение, получив доступ к узлам.

Поэтому то, что для вас выглядит внешне одинаково `x => x.MyProperty` для компилятора является совсем разными вещами: в одном случае может сделать разбор и компилируется в разбираемые вещи, в другом — компилируется в другие вещи, в которых не сохраняется информация.

В качестве примера ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668812/213987), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/863676/213987), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987)) могу привести конструируемые на клиенте выражения, которые потом на сервере заново разбираются и компилируются в SQL-выражения, чтобы был не IEnumerable, выполняемый на клиенте, а был IQueryable, выполняемый на сервере. Они все построены на базе Expression, там нигде не может быть просто Func.

Поэтому и вам не попадается таких примеров, сколько вы не ищете.